# Rotate sphere based on texture coordinates in Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, camera, geometry

I have sphere with a Texture2D.
I have one camera which looks at the sphere.
I have a script which returns the coordinates from where i click with the mouse.

Is it possible to rotate the sphere object when the mouse clicks, so that the coordinates is what the camera looks at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I asked on UnityAnswers aswell. Here is the solution http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/561417/rotate-sphere-based-on-texture-coordinates.html